# Marketing Developer Platform app review email

Tags: linkedin-api

I created an app entitled Yachties Article Post on the 2nd May but never received the Marketing Developer Platform app review email. I have searched my emails including junk mail. Please could you resend this to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer service question for LinkedIn, which aren't on-topic for StackOverflow no matter what LinkedIn support claim.

Comment: same problem. I was sent here because of missing email https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714599/access-to-marketing-developer-platform and I was told that they cannot help me with this problem on stackoverflow (of course).